# Pointer returning as nil in obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sparrow-framework

I'm initialising a pointer to a SPSprite object (sparrow framework) like this...

```
SPSprite *mySprite = [[SPSprite alloc] init];
```

I'm then saving that pointer in a NSMutableDictionary like this...

```
[objectDynamic setObject:mySprite forKey:@"objectSprite"];
```

But when I try to access that object at a later point in the code with this...

```
SPSprite *mySprite = [objectDynamic objectForKey:@"objectSprite"];
```

mySprite = 0x00000000 when I look at it in the debugger, when I do a print though on objectDynamic I get this..

```
objectSprite = "<SPSprite: 0x162e7d40>";
```

Which is the same as it was when it as alloc'd/initalised, so I'm a tad confused as to what's going on.

I'm using ARC.

Comment: Are you certain that you're using the same key in `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:`?

Comment: Check if you have an (invisible) typo in the key literals. Or use a constant global string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your key is the same (in fact, I would #define it so you avoid typos).